# Sending JSON data to PHP with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to write a jQuery function to send a query string to a PHP script, but I can't seem to get the text to get to the server in the correct format. I want to send this query string (with the appropriate URL encoding):

```
data={"name":"Chris"}
```

where 'data' is always a JSON string. Using jQuery's `.ajax` function I tried setting my data variable to

```
data: { 'data': {"name":"chris"} },
```

but PHP ends up getting:

```
data[name]=chris
```

What's the proper way to send the data back to the server so that the JSON string is properly reserved, without having to hand-craft the string?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do

Comment: Have you set the datatype as 'json' ?
dataType: 'json'

Comment: dataType is for the data coming from the server. I'm trying to send JSON data to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to use [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) because jQuery does not include the capability to output JSON, only to parse it, and the method we will be using is not supported in IE 6/7. Convert your JavaScript object to JSON:

```
var encoded = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Then you need to include that JSON-formatted string as request data:

```
$.getJSON(url, {data: encoded}, function() { ... });
```

**Edit:** An older version of this post referred to the jquery-json plugin, but it's obvious that that plug-in was written when jQuery 1.3.x was current.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is put quotes around the string

```
data: { 'data': '{"name":"chris"}' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, unclear from your question, if you are trying to know how to handle JSON strings properly in PHP, the best way would be to use the functions `json_encode` and `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
data: { 'data': {"name":"chris"} },
```

You get a indexed array with key of name and value of chris.

this is right:

```
{ name : "chris" }
```

If you want in php:

```
 name = "chris";
```

Then you must send

```
 { name : "chris" }
```

Depending on if you GET you can get:

```
$name = $_GET["name"]; 

echo $name; // chris
```